# How to form semi-circular text in gimp or photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, gimp, inkscape, photoshop-effects

I am not trying to wrap  text around a semi-circle but form a semi-circle with text.
Basically the font will gradually increase from left to middle and then decrease from middle to right.
Can photoshop or gimp be used for doing this?
Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Using GIMP, you can write your text as normal and then use the `filters->Distort->Curve Bend` filter - it allows you to draw your desired arc with control points.

[image: GIMP with teh Curve Bend plug-in]

Unfortunately the filter uses a simple linear interpolation which let the borders fuzzy, so if you are using GIMP, you should work with a higher resolution than the one intended for the final result, and use the `colors->curves` tool to sharpen the contrast at the edges after applying the effect and scaling down.

To avoid these sad effects, you should use a vector-based program to create your text, and them copy it over to a raster program if you need a raster image. In Inkscape, for example, you can write your text, convert it to curves (`Object->Object To Path`), open the `Paths->Path Effect Editor...` and with the text selected, add an `Envelop Deformation` effect from the drop down list - then just click on the first icon after the `Top bend path` entry to edit the contour of the upper bound of the text directly on canvas. This approach gives you crisp text in any scale, and better control than GIMP's curve bend.

[image: Inkscape and the Envelope Deformation path filter]

Answer (score 2):

In Photoshop, you could use the `create warped text` tool.

Start off by creating your text:

[image]

Highlight your text and click this little "T" with the line under it:

[image]

Choose `Arc Upper` as the `Style` and then choose the amount of bend you want:

[image]

Click OK to set your bend:

[image]

Comment: I suppose the app. shown here is Photoshop. It should be specified since the question covers anyone of 5 different applications.

Comment: I have edited my answer but the title of question does say "How to form semi-circular text in _gimp_ or _photoshop_?" so it was pretty obvious anyway.